# Compute dynamic range in a linear quantization system

Tags: dynamic-range-compression

I know the **dynamic range** is the ratio between the maximum amplitude and the minimum amplitude of a signal, calculating the dynamic range in *dB* I get a difference of logarithms:

[image: dynamic_range = maxAmp/minAmp]

But why the dynamic range of a *N*-bit digital system with linear quantization is *6N dB*?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/66274/22061) over at Electronics.SE.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks, but that answer is about SNR that is different from the dynamic range...

Comment: It's exactly the same calculation, have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range#Audio).

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize the comments, for the next person who comes looking:

decibels are $20 \log_{10}{x}$ (or $10 \log_{10}{\left( x^2 \right) }$ when *power* levels used instead of the *amplitude* levels)

When looking at bit noise limited N-bit system, there are $2^{N}$ measurement levels, and the smallest distinguishable difference is $1$. So

DR$_{dB}$ = $20 \log_{10}{\frac{2^N}{1} } = N*20\log_{10}{2}\approx 6 N$

Comment: Also see this answer here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41497/snr-of-a-16-bit-dsp-with-12-bit-adc-40-bit-accumulator/41509#41509 which may help give further insight.

Comment: And this one: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal/40261#40261

Answer (score 0):

For an A/D converter (or an equivalent quantizer with both finite precision and range of measured amplitude), I would define **Dynamic Range** in dB of that A/D to be the sum of dB of *Signal-to-Noise ratio* (S/N) plus dB of *Headroom* plus dB of *Crest Factor*.  For a fixed crest factor, as the signal level increases (against a constant quantization noise floor), the S/N increases, but the headroom dB decreases by about the same amount.